# Como definir uma tabela com chave composta no SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Estou fazendo um banco de dados embarcado como meio de campo na integração entre dois sistemas. O sistema `A`, onde tem os dados, exporta todos os seus dados para o sistema `B` já devidamente mapeado.

Entretanto, se eu quiser performance, `A` só deveria enviar para `B` as alterações realizadas. Então, aí entra o meio de campo, `M`.

`B` informa a sua estrutura para `M`, por exemplo:

```
{
  "colunas": [
    {"chave":true,"nome":"cd_meio_pgto"},
    {"nome":"ds_meio_pgto","chave":true}
  ],
  "nome_tabela":"meio_pagamento"
}
```

Porém podem rolar chaves compostas. Por exemplo:

```
{
  "colunas": [
    {"chave":true,"nome":"cd_meio_pgto"},
    {"nome":"ds_meio_pgto","chave":true},
    {"nome":"chave_01","chave":true}
  ],
  "nome_tabela":"meio_pagamento_exemplo"
}
```

Para a integração funcionar perfeitamente, preciso que `M` seja capaz de, embarcadamente, mantenha uma cópia boa o suficiente de `A'` (os dados em `A` após aplicados os mapeamentos) com os dados informados por `B`.

Para base embarcada, estamos estudando usar SQLite. Porém, como criar chave primária composta no SQLite?

Considerando as colunas todas do tipo `TEXT` (ou ignorando totalmente, já que o SQLite permite isso), como ficariam as tabelas `meio_pagamento`? E `meio_pagamento_exemplo`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Achei seguindo o caminho da [domentação](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html) através [dessa outra resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/734704/4438007).

Basicamente, se só existir uma única coluna pertencente à chave primária, podemos colocar a expressão reservada `PRIMARY KEY` na coluna específica.

> If the keywords PRIMARY KEY are added to a column definition, then the primary key for the table consists of that single column
>
> Se as palavras reservadas PRIMARY KEY foram adicionadas à definição de uma coluna, então a chave primária da tabela consiste dessa única coluna

```
CREATE TABLE meio_pagamento (
  cd_meio_pgto TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
  ds_meio_pgto TEXT
)
```

Porém, não podemos extrapolar esse comportamento para múltiplas colunas:

> An error is raised if more than one PRIMARY KEY clause appears in a CREATE TABLE statement
>
> Um erro é lançado se mais do que uma cláusula PRIMARY KEY aparecer em uma declaração CREATE TABLE

> Portanto, o seguinte está errado:
>
> ```
> CREATE TABLE meio_pagamento_exemplo (
>   cd_meio_pgto TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
>   chave_01 TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
>   ds_meio_pgto TEXT
> )
> ```

A alternativa correta para fazer múltiplas colunas na mesma chave primária é colocar a chave primária como uma restrição à tabela.

> if a PRIMARY KEY clause is specified as a table-constraint, then the primary key of the table consists of the list of columns specified as part of the PRIMARY KEY clause
>
> se uma cláusula PRIMARY KEY é especificada como uma restrição de tabela, então a chave primária da tabela consiste da lista das colunas especificadas como parte da cláusula PRIMARY KEY

```
CREATE TABLE meio_pagamento_exemplo (  
  cd_meio_pgto TEXT,  
  chave_01 TEXT,  
  ds_meio_pgto TEXT,
  PRIMARY KEY (cd_meio_pgto, chave_01)
)
```

Note que, inclusive, esse jeito de escrever também funciona para chaves primárias de uma única coluna. É como se colocar `PRIMARY KEY` ao lado da definição da coluna fosse um açúcar sintático para a forma da `PRIMARY KEY` como sendo uma restrição. Então, o seguinte código também é válido:

```
CREATE TABLE meio_pagamento (  
  cd_meio_pgto TEXT,
  ds_meio_pgto TEXT,
  PRIMARY KEY (cd_meio_pgto)
)
```

---

Se você estiver trabalhando com Java, tem a garantia que **sempre haverá** chave primária e deseja fazer isso programaticamente sobre um [`org.json.JSONObject`](https://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/org/json/JSONObject.html):

```java
JSONObject descricaoTabela = "{\r\n" + 
            "  \"colunas\": [\r\n" + 
            "    {\"chave\":true,\"nome\":\"cd_meio_pgto\"},\r\n" + 
            "    {\"nome\":\"ds_meio_pgto\",\"chave\":true}\r\n" + 
            "  ],\r\n" + 
            "  \"nome_tabela\":\"meio_pagamento\"\r\n" + 
            "}\r\n" + 
            "";
String nomeTabela = descricaoTabela.getString("nome_tabela");

List<Coluna> colunas = new ArrayList<>();
JSONArray descricaoColunas = descricaoTabela.getJSONArray("colunas");
for (int i = 0; i < descricaoColunas.length(); i++) {
  JSONObject descricaoColuna= descricaoColunas.getJSONObject(i);
  colunas.add(new Coluna(descricaoColuna.getString("nome"), descricaoColuna.optBoolean("chave")));
}
String sql = String.format("CREATE TABLE %s (%s, PRIMARY KEY (%s))",
            descricaoTabela.getString("nome_tabela"),
            colunas.stream().map(Coluna::getNome).map(c -> c + " TEXT").collect(Collectors.joining(",")),
            colunas.stream().filter(Coluna::isChave).map(Coluna::getNome).collect(Collectors.joining(","))
     );
```

Usando de maneira mais esperto o `Collectors.joining`, podemos usar como prefixo `", PRIMARY KEY ("` e sufixo `")"`, assim podemos retirar a restrição de que a chave primária deveria ser mandatória:

```java
JSONObject descricaoTabela = "{\r\n" + 
            "  \"colunas\": [\r\n" + 
            "    {\"chave\":true,\"nome\":\"cd_meio_pgto\"},\r\n" + 
            "    {\"nome\":\"ds_meio_pgto\",\"chave\":true}\r\n" + 
            "  ],\r\n" + 
            "  \"nome_tabela\":\"meio_pagamento\"\r\n" + 
            "}\r\n" + 
            "";
String nomeTabela = descricaoTabela.getString("nome_tabela");

List<Coluna> colunas = new ArrayList<>();
JSONArray descricaoColunas = descricaoTabela.getJSONArray("colunas");
for (int i = 0; i < descricaoColunas.length(); i++) {
  JSONObject descricaoColuna= descricaoColunas.getJSONObject(i);
  colunas.add(new Coluna(descricaoColuna.getString("nome"), descricaoColuna.optBoolean("chave")));
}
String sql = String.format("CREATE TABLE %s (%s%s)",
            descricaoTabela.getString("nome_tabela"),
            colunas.stream().map(Coluna::getNome).map(c -> c + " TEXT").collect(Collectors.joining(",")),
            colunas.stream().filter(Coluna::isChave).map(Coluna::getNome)
                .collect(Collectors.joining(/*separador*/",", /*prefixo*/", PRIMARY KEY (", /*sufixo*/")"))
     );
```

Comment: @VictorStafusa, agradeço a sugestão de alteração, mas eu realmente não deseja que o código errado esteja facilmente legível, mas disponível para quem realmente deseja ver. Por isso criei [esta questão](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7727/64969) no meta. Não estando prontamente visível, evita que pessoas em leitura dinâmica ou que não tenham conhecimento façam uma leitura equivocada do código. Assim que voltar do almoço tratarei o esconder o código errado de acordo com as sugestões das respostas do meta

Comment: Bem, ok, você que sabe. Mas não acho que exista muita gente que leia códigos aleatoriamente aqui no SOPT sem ler também todo o texto ao redor, ainda mais quando a resposta é grande e trata-se de um trecho no meio dela.